# How to create a GUI via R?

Tags: r, plot, interactive

Now I have several parameters for my plotting. So I want to create a GUI, with some sliders for controlling continuous parameters, some check boxes/option buttons for controlling logical parameters and a dialog box for choosing data files. When I change the parameters, I hope my plot can change immediately. I did some quick search like "r control" or "r interactive" but didn't find interesting stuff. Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is [an entire section in the R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces) devoted to the *web interfaces* aspect of this.  The newest contender is [shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) which is definitely worth looking at too.

If you want desktop GUIs, this is a FAQ too as R had this via the tcltk package a for decade+, and there is the excellent [gWidgets abstraction](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/index.html) by John Verzani et al.

Comment: Hey, Dirk. I am using your Rcpp too! Thanks for your answer and your works.

Comment: If you want to it the 'hard way', there are examples in the RInside package which do this via Qt (for a GUI) and Wt (for a webapp) as well. But in most cases you probably want this in R, not C++.

Comment: I mean other parts of what I am doing, not this plotting. And I think *Shiny* is cool enough.